# r language: how to find rows with match in list?

Tags: r

In R, if I have a data frame with a column for which each row entry contains a list, how can I search for those rows containing a match in that list?

For example, how can I return the indices for those rows containing "Algebra" (e.g. rows 1 and 3) in the following:

```
> df[1:3,]$classes
[[1]]
[1] "Algebra"          "Calculus"

[[2]]
[1] "Geometry"

[[3]]
[1] "Geometry" "Quantum Mechanics"   "Algebra"
```

Comment: thanks @akrun, this reports the index location in the list where the match occurs (and 0 if no match). Can this be modified to have TRUE/FALSE output per row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `sapply` to loop over the `list`, use `grepl` to get logical vector, wrap with `any` to return only a single `TRUE/FALSE` value per `list` element.

```
sapply(df[1:3,]$classes, function(x) any(grepl('Algebra', x)))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or we can use `%in%` to return only a single `TRUE/FALSE` per `list` element.

```
sapply(df[1:3,]$classes, '%in%', x='Algebra')
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Another option is `is.element`

```
sapply(df[1:3,]$classes, is.element, el='Algebra')
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Or as @Richard Scriven mentioned, `==` can be used

```
sapply(df[1:3,]$classes, function(x) any(x == "Algebra"))
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect. I like the `which()` version you had as well to return only those indices with match.

Comment: @user46688 Wrapping with `which` gives the row index, but either one of those can be used for subsetting.

Comment: You could also use `==` since you're just looking for one word. `sapply(df[1:3,]$classes, function(x) any(x == "Algebra"))`